Not able to see gradle.kts code properly in Android Studio
i´m new in gradle in kotlin and I´m developing a simple Task in kotlin. It works just fine, but i´m not able to see this file in a "pretty" way. Meaning that Android Studio is not just showing the code like other files.
This is my code
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import java.io.File

apply(plugin = "kotlin-android")

class ModulePathFactory(
    private val path: String,
    private val file: File
) {
    private var parentFile = file

    private fun createPath():List<String> {
        return path.split(".")
    }
    fun createDir(): File {
        var moduleDirectory: File? = null
        createPath().forEach { pathName ->
            val file = File(parentFile, pathName)
            val result = file.mkdirs()
            parentFile = file
        }
        return parentFile
    }
}

class PathManager {
    companion object {
        private const val pathRegex = "^\\.\\./[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*\$"
        private const val moduleNameRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\$"
    }

    fun getAbsolutePath(rawPath: String): String {
        val regex = Regex(pathRegex)
        if (!regex.matches(rawPath)) return ""
        val split = rawPath.split("../").first { it.isNotBlank() }.split("/")
        val regex2 = Regex(moduleNameRegex)
        if (split.any { !regex2.matches(it) }) return ""
        return "../".repeat(split.size)
    }
    fun getSettingPath(rawPath: String, moduleName: String): String {
        val regex = Regex(pathRegex)
        if (!regex.matches(rawPath)) return ""
        val split = rawPath.split("../").first { it.isNotBlank() }.split("/")
        val regex2 = Regex(moduleNameRegex)
        if (split.any { !regex2.matches(it) }) return ""
        return """
          include "${getPath(rawPath,moduleName)}"
          project("${getPath(rawPath,moduleName)}").projectDir = file("$rawPath/$moduleName")
        """
    }

    fun getGradlePath(rawPath:String): String {
        val regex = Regex(pathRegex)
        if (!regex.matches(rawPath)) return ""
        val split = rawPath.split("../").first { it.isNotBlank() }.split("/")
        val regex2 = Regex(moduleNameRegex)
        if (split.any { !regex2.matches(it) }) return ""
        return "apply from:" + "../".repeat( split.size + 1) + "common-android-library-config.gradle" + "\n" +
                "apply from:" + "'kotlin-kapt'"
    }

    fun getPath(rawPath:String, moduleName: String): String {
        val regex = Regex(pathRegex)
        val regex2 = Regex(moduleNameRegex)
        if (!regex.matches(rawPath) || !regex2.matches(moduleName)) return ""
        val split: List<String> = ("$rawPath/$moduleName").split("../")
        if (split.any { !regex.matches(rawPath) }) return ""
        return split.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }.joinToString("").split("/").joinToString("") { ":$it" }
    }
}

open class GenerateAndroidModuleTask : DefaultTask() {
    @Input
    lateinit var packageName: String
    @Input
    lateinit var rootName: String
    @Input
    lateinit var moduleName: String
    @Input
    lateinit var mustBeDeployed: String
    @TaskAction
    fun generateModule() {
        println("rootName:" + rootName)
        println("moduleName:" +moduleName)
        println("packageName:"+ packageName)
        val pathManager = PathManager()
        val moduleFile = File(rootName, moduleName)
        moduleFile.mkdirs()

        val srcFile = ModulePathFactory(
            path = "src.",
            file = moduleFile
        ).createDir()


        File(srcFile, "AndroidManifest.xml").writeText(
            """
            <manifest package="$packageName" />
            """.trimIndent()
        )

        File(moduleFile, "build.gradle").writeText(
            """
           ${pathManager.getGradlePath(rootName)}

           android {
               defaultConfig {
                   versionName "${'$'}moduleVersion"
               }
               buildTypes {
                   sdkRelease {
                       minifyEnabled false
                   }
               }
           }

           afterEvaluate {
               publishing {
                   registerMavenPublishing(it, moduleVersion, "${PathManager().getAbsolutePath(rootName+"/"+moduleName)}", "$moduleName", "$packageName")
               }
            }
            """.trimIndent()
        )

        File(moduleFile, ".gitignore").writeText(
            """
            /build
            """.trimIndent()
        )


        ModulePathFactory(
            path = "main.java.com",
            file = srcFile
        ).createDir()

        val settingsFile = File("settings.gradle")

        val currentSettings = settingsFile.readText()

        if (!currentSettings.contains(pathManager.getSettingPath(rootName,moduleName))) {
            settingsFile.writeText(currentSettings + pathManager.getSettingPath(rootName,moduleName))
        }
    }
}

tasks.register<GenerateAndroidModuleTask>("createModule") {
    this.packageName = project.findProperty("packageName")?.toString() ?: ""
    this.rootName = project.findProperty("rootName")?.toString() ?: ""
    this.moduleName = project.findProperty("moduleName")?.toString() ?: ""
    this.mustBeDeployed = project.findProperty("mustBeDeployed")?.toString() ?: ""
}

but is showing like this

I would like to see it like this example ( different colors )

I was not able to find any example.
What I´m doing wrong?
Thanks in advanced.
